# removePersistentStore(_:) doesn't return Bool in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to store the return value of `removePersistentStore(_:)` which is clearly a `Bool` according to the documentation:

[image: Doc]

I'm using it like that:

```
let removed = try! storeCoordinator.removePersistentStore(store)
```

But get an alert that `removed` is just `Void`:
[image: Alert]

What's the deal with this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Return Value**
>
> `YES` if the store is removed, otherwise `NO`.

in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` documentation refers to the Objective-C signature of
the method:

```
- (BOOL)removePersistentStore:(NSPersistentStore *)store
                    error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error
```

In Swift, the method throws an error *instead of* returning a boolean:

```
func removePersistentStore(_ store: NSPersistentStore) throws
```

so that you can call it as

```
try! storeCoordinator.removePersistentStore(persistentStore)
```

or better:

```
do { 
    try storeCoordinator.removePersistentStore(persistentStore)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("failed", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Compare [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference:

> If the last non-block parameter of an Objective-C method is of type NSError **, Swift replaces it with the throws keyword, to indicate that the method can throw an error.
> ...
> If an error producing Objective-C method returns a BOOL value to indicate the success or failure of a method call, Swift changes the return type of the function to Void.